# server-side event bubbling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, eventemitter

I have a class/prototype that extends the `EventEmitter` class. Multiple of them get created and right now I store them in a simple object by id.

I've hit a spot where it would greatly simplify things if I could listen to the collection of them for events instead of each individually.

Ideally the collection object would bubble the events up and emit up the `event`, `id`, and any data that is normally emitted to the collection would simplify many things.

What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for a way to namespace your events. Checkout out the [EventEmitter2 project](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2) either to consume or poke around the source code for guidance.